# How to view the first element of the group via Scrollintoview()?

Tags: javascript, html, js-scrollintoview

I'm trying to make some simple buttons to hide some elements in a group, and then make some `scrollIntoView` buttons to view the "first" visible instances of these elements when clicked. Hiding functions work fine, but viewing functions always go to the last element of the same class name. How to make them go to the first ones? I'm not experienced with javascript, so I'm sorry if my codes are repeating too much. Here's the HTML part:

```
<div class="element1 a">Element 1A</div>
<div class="element1 b">Element 1B</div>
<div class="element1 c">Element 1C</div>

<div class="element2 a">Element 2A</div>
<div class="element2 b">Element 2B</div>
<div class="element2 c">Element 2C</div>

<div class="element3 a">Element 3A</div>
<div class="element3 b">Element 3B</div>
<div class="element3 c">Element 3C</div>


<div class="hide" onclick="hide1()">Hide 1</div>
<div class="hide" onclick="hide2()">Hide 2</div>
<div class="hide" onclick="hide3()">Hide 3</div>

<div class="view" onclick="viewa()">View A</div>
<div class="view" onclick="viewb()">View B</div>
<div class="view" onclick="viewc()">View C</div>
```

The following functions work fine to hide the classes 1, 2 and 3:

```
function hide1() {
var i; var div = document.getElementsByClassName("element1");
for (i=0; i<div.length; i++) {div[i].style.display = "none";}
}

function hide2() {
var i; var div = document.getElementsByClassName("element2");
for (i=0; i<div.length; i++) {div[i].style.display = "none";}
}

function hide3() {
var i; var div = document.getElementsByClassName("element3");
for (i=0; i<div.length; i++) {div[i].style.display = "none";}
}
```

And here's the part I have problem. When I hide a class by using the buttons above, the functions below always view the "last" visible instances of a, b or c. How should I edit this part in a simple way to view the "first" visible instances instead?

```
function viewa() {
var i; var div = document.getElementsByClassName("a");
for(i=0; i<div.length; i++){div[i].scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"})};
}

function viewb() {
var i; var div = document.getElementsByClassName("b");
for(i=0; i<div.length; i++){div[i].scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"})};
}

function viewc() {
var i; var div = document.getElementsByClassName("c");
for(i=0; i<div.length; i++){div[i].scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"})};
}
```

**EXAMPLE:**
When the button "View A" is clicked, it scrolls to "Element 3A", but I want it to scroll to "Element 1A"...
When the button "Hide 1" is clicked first, and then "View A" is clicked, then it scrolls to "Element 3A" again, but I want it to scroll to "Element 2A" this time, since Element 1A is hidden now.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question, can you try to explain more how you want the code to work? what do you mean by "show first" or last? Do you mean the order of the elements? if so - it has nothing to do with scrollintoview();, this function is scrolling the screen like you do with your mouse-wheel or the scrollbar, and btw you cannot name a class only a number

Comment: Thanks for correction. I'm changing their names as `element1, element2 and element3` now, sorry... Let me try to explain my issue with an example: When I click "Hide 1" button, it hides `Element 1A, Element 1B, and Element 1C`. And then when I click "View A" button, it scrolls to the `Element 3A`, but I'd like it to scroll to `Element 2A`. Since Element 1A is hidden, Element 2A is being the "first" remaining element of "A" instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you trigger (for example) the `viewa` function, you're looping through all the elements with class 'a'. And then trigger the `scrollIntoView` function on those elements. So what you're basically doing is triggering `scrollIntoView` 3 times in a very short time, overruling the previous call with the next one every time. This explains why it always focuses on Element 3A (as it is the last element in the for loop).

What you want to do instead of looping through all elements, is find the first visible element:

```js
document.querySelector('.a:not([style="display: none;"])')
```

This finds the first element with class "a" that does not have a style property of `"display: none;"` (which is what you're using to hide elements in the `hide1` function).

So to fix your code:

```js
function viewa() {
    let el = document.querySelector('.a:not([style="display: none;"])')
    el.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" })};
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation, but in your fix view buttons stop working after the hide button is clicked. For example, it scrolls to "1A" when I click "View A", but nothing happens if I first click on "Hide 1" and then "View A". It's supposed to go to "2A" in that case. Do you know what's the problem? (PS: Last curly bracket is unnecessary in your fix)

Comment: Ah yes, minor typo on my end. The querySelector() call is very picky about spaces. So i had `"display:none"`, but it has to be `"display: none;"`. Updated my answer accordingly :-). 

A better/more robust fix for this would be to use the `hidden` html attribute, and add/remove that when you click the hidea() function. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/avbzcpef/